# How to create subquery in Querydsl

Tags: querydsl, notin

I am new to Querydsl. I have to convert following query into Querydsl. I tried like below but I am not getting result.

Can any one please tell me what I am missing or any thing doing wrong in query?

```
select * from room  as room 
      where room.nroom_id not in(
                          select rdm.nroom_id from roomdepartmentmapping as rdm)
```

I tried like this

```
    JPAQuery<Tuple> query = new JPAQuery<Tuple>(em);  

    query.from(room) 
         .where(room.nRoomId.notIn
                         (query.select(roomDepartmentMapping.nRoomId)
                               .from(roomDepartmentMapping)
                         )
               );
```

**Console**

```
   at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:31) ~[querydsl-core-4.1.4.jar:na]
        at com.querydsl.core.types.OperationImpl.accept(OperationImpl.java:83) ~[querydsl-core-4.1.4.jar:na]
        at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.handle(SerializerBase.java:92) ~[querydsl-core-4.1.4.jar:na]
        at com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLSerializer.serialize(JPQLSerializer.java:220) ~[querydsl-jpa-4.1.4.jar:na]
        at com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLSerializer.visit(JPQLSerializer.java:358) ~[querydsl-jpa-4.1.4.jar:na]
        at com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLSerializer.visit(JPQLSerializer.java:39) ~[querydsl-jpa-4.1.4.jar:na]
        at com.querydsl.core.types.SubQueryExpressionImpl.accept(SubQueryExpressionImpl.java:57) ~[querydsl-core-4.1.4.jar:na]
        at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.handle(SerializerBase.java:92) ~[querydsl-core-4.1.4.jar:na]            
        at com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLSerializer.visitOperation(JPQLSerializer.java:403) ~[querydsl-jpa-4.1.4.jar:na]
        at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:231) ~[querydsl-core-4.1.4.jar:na]
        at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:31) ~[querydsl-core-4.1.4.jar:na]
        at com.querydsl.core.types.OperationImpl.accept(OperationImpl.java:83) ~[querydsl-core-4.1.4.jar:na]
        at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.handle(SerializerBase.java:92) ~[querydsl-core-4.1.4.jar:na]
        at com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLSerializer.serialize(JPQLSerializer.java:220) ~[querydsl-jpa-4.1.4.jar:na]
        at com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLSerializer.visit(JPQLSerializer.java:358) ~[querydsl-jpa-4.1.4.jar:na]
        at com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLSerializer.visit(JPQLSerializer.java:39) ~[querydsl-jpa-4.1.4.jar:na]
        at com.querydsl.core.types.SubQueryExpressionImpl.accept(SubQueryExpressionImpl.java:57) ~[querydsl-core-4.1.4.jar:na]
        at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.handle(SerializerBase.java:92) ~[querydsl-core-4.1.4.jar:na]
        at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visitOperation(SerializerBase.java:270) ~[querydsl-core-4.1.4.jar:na]
        at com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLSerializer.visitOperation(JPQLSerializer.java:403) ~[querydsl-jpa-4.1.4.jar:na]
        at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:231) ~[querydsl-core-4.1.4.jar:na]           
        at com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLSerializer.visit(JPQLSerializer.java:39) ~[querydsl-jpa-4.1.4.jar:na]
        at com.querydsl.core.types.SubQueryExpressionImpl.accept(SubQueryExpressionImpl.java:57) ~[querydsl-core-4.1.4.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than using the instance of the enclosing query, an instance of `JPASubQuery` is required. You can use `new JPASubQuery()` or the convenience method `JPAExpressions.select`. Your query should look something like this:

```
JPAQuery<Tuple> query = new JPAQuery<Tuple>(em);  

query.from(room) 
     .where(room.nRoomId.notIn
                     (JPAExpressions.select(roomDepartmentMapping.nRoomId)
                           .from(roomDepartmentMapping)
                     )
           );
```

Comment: Tanks its working. Can you please check this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52111072/spring-with-querydsl-null-pointer-exception`