# Spring with Querydsl : Null Pointer Exception

Tags: spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I am trying to implement Search filter functionality and load grid in `spring boot data JPA` application. For creating dynamic query I am using `Querydsl`.

I am searching data according to sFloor and nBuildId.

1. If I am passing sFloor, nBuildId only that matching record should display in grid
2. If I am not passing any values then grid should load with all values.

I tried like below In that when I am passing data I am able to filter data. But when I am not passing any records I am getting `null pointer exception`.

**RoomController**

```
@GetMapping("/getUnclaimedRoomDetails")
public List<Tuple> populateUnclaimedRoomGridView(@RequestParam(value="nBuildId", required=false) Integer nBuildId,
                                                 @RequestParam(value="sFloor", required=false) String sFloor) {
    return roomService.loadUnclamiedRoomGrid(nBuildId,sFloor);

}
```

**RoomService**

```
public  List<Tuple> loadUnclamiedRoomGrid(Integer nBuildId, String sFloor) {

    QRoom room = QRoom.room;        
    QRoomDepartmentMapping roomDepartmentMapping = QRoomDepartmentMapping.roomDepartmentMapping;

    JPAQuery<Tuple> query = new JPAQuery<Tuple>(em);

    query.from(room) 
         .where(room.nRoomId.notIn
                     (JPAExpressions.select(roomDepartmentMapping.nRoomId)
                           .from(roomDepartmentMapping)
                     )
           );

    if (nBuildId != 0) {
        query.where(room.nBuildId.eq(nBuildId));
    }

    if(sFloor != null) {
        query.where(room.sFloor.eq(sFloor));
    }       

return query.fetch();   

}
```

Can any one please tell me why I am getting null pointer exception instead of all data?

Comment: On which line do you get the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is `if (nBuildId != 0)`. `nBuildId` is a big `Integer` so when the check is being performed it is being unboxed to a primitive `int`. If it's null, this will cause a `NullPointerException`. A null check on `nBuildId` should fix things, E.G. `if (nBuildId != null && nBuildId != 0)`.

Comment: its working properly Thank you. one more thing is I want particular column from Query Result. so  How I can iterate this List<Tuple>

Comment: I tried by using for each loop but getting class cast exception  ` List<Tuple> queryResult = query.fetch();
  
  for(Tuple row : queryResult) {
   
   System.out.println("Build Id " +row.get(room.nBuildId));
  }

Comment: Raise a separate question as this is unrelated to the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Ok. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52114040/spring-with-querydsl-java-lang-classcastexception`